# Xamarin.Formsで作成したアプリの終了ボタンを作成したいです。

Tags: xamarin

Xamarinを始めたばかりです。

Xamain.Formsで、AndroidとUWPを対象とするアプリを作成しています。
そのアプリに、アプリ終了ボタンを作成したいのですが、どのように行えばいいのか分かりません。

以下のサイトを真似してみました。
http://makopy5la6.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/03/25/172342
すると、Androidの方ではアプリを終了することができました。
このサンプルは、プラットフォーム毎に処理を作成していると思うのですが、
UWPの方に関してはサンプルが無かったので、どうしたものかと。
Android版を真似てUWP版を作成し、以下に該当する箇所をUWP用に変えればよいかと
思っているのですが、どのような処理をしたらよいのか...。
調べている最中ですがまだ分からず、ここに質問させていただきました。

```
public void Exit()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
}
```

このようなサイトでの質問も初めてなので、情報不足ありましたら
ご指摘ください。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下でアプリ終了できましたっ！
Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Exit();